# Managing and substringing multiple strings in a matrix (Python & Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, substring

I have a file titled "test.fa" that reads:

```
>Sequence 1
TCAGAACCAGTTATAAATTTATCATTTCCTTCTCCACTCCT
>Sequence 2
CCCACGCAGCCGCCCTCCTCCCCGGTCACTGACTGGTCCTG
>Sequence 3
TCGACCCTCTGGAACCTATCAGGGACCACAGTCAGCCAGGCAAG
>Sequence 4
AAAACACTTGAGGGAGCAGATAACTGGGCCAACCATGACTC
```

This test file only has 8 lines, but could have more. I also don't now the length of all sequences. So first I count the number of lines, and create a matrix based on the number of lines.

```
import numpy as np
filename = "test.fa"
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    n1 = 0
    n2 = 0
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[0] != '>':
            m1 = 1
            n1 = n1 + m1
        else:
            m2 = 1
            n2 = n2 + m2
    seq = np.chararray((n1,2),itemsize = 99)
```

Next, I add values to the matrix.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    n3 = -1
    n4 = -1
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[0] != '>':
            m3 = 1
            n3 = n3 + m3
            seq[n3,1] = line
        else:
            m4 = 1
            n4 = n4 + m4
            seq[n4,0] = line
```

If I call 'seq' I get:

```
chararray([[b'>Sequence 1', b'TCAGAACCAGTTATAAATTTATCATTTCCTTCTCCACTCCT'],
       [b'>Sequence 2', b'CCCACGCAGCCGCCCTCCTCCCCGGTCACTGACTGGTCCTG'],
       [b'>Sequence 3', b'TCGACCCTCTGGAACCTATCAGGGACCACAGTCAGCCAGGCAAG'],
       [b'>Sequence 4', b'AAAACACTTGAGGGAGCAGATAACTGGGCCAACCATGACTC']], dtype='|S99')

seq[2,1]: b'TCGACCCTCTGGAACCTATCAGGGACCACAGTCAGCCAGGCAAG'
seq[2,1][0] : 84
seq[2,1][0:8] : b'TCGACCCT'
seq[2,8][8] : 67
seq[2,1][8:9] : C
```

This doesn’t feel like the best way manage this data (and why does [2,1][0] return 84?). I am not sure np.chararray with itemsize of 99 is the best approach.

My question is: What is a better way to organize/manage this data? I eventually need to count the occurrences of each nucleotide ( i.e. how many As, Ts, Cs, Gs), and pull substrings from each sequence. For context, this relates to Expectation Maximization and Gibbs Sampling.

Comment: seq[2,1][0] return 84, which is decimal ascii code of T (seq[2,1][0])

Comment: I don't think `numpy` arrays help you much.  Lists and python strings are better suited to line-by-line creation and looking for substrings.  With list and list.append you wouldn't need to read the file twice.  And you wouldn't have to worry about fixed string size of numpy string dtypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `np.chararray`, you get an array with an `S` dtype, bytestrings:

```
In [145]: x = np.chararray((1,),10)                                                            
In [146]: x[0]='ACT'                                                                           
In [147]: x                                                                                    
Out[147]: chararray([b'ACT'], dtype='|S10')
In [148]: x[0]                                                                                 
Out[148]: b'ACT'
In [149]: x[0][0]                                                                              
Out[149]: 65
In [150]: x[0][1]                                                                              
Out[150]: 67
In [151]: x[0][2]                                                                              
Out[151]: 84
```

That's one byte per character.  ASCII code of `A` is 65; `T` is 19 characters further.

Did you see the `chararray` note:

> The `chararray` class exists for backwards compatibility with
>      Numarray, it is not recommended for new development. Starting from numpy
>      1.4, if one needs arrays of strings, it is recommended to use arrays of
>      `dtype` `object_`, `string_` or `unicode_`, and use the free functions
>      in the `numpy.char` module for fast vectorized string operations.

```
In [159]: x = np.array([b'ACT'])                                                               
In [160]: x                                                                                    
Out[160]: array([b'ACT'], dtype='|S3')
In [161]: x[0]                                                                                 
Out[161]: b'ACT'
In [162]: x[0][0]                                                                              
Out[162]: 65
```

If instead we use the Py3 default string type (unicode):

```
In [154]: x = np.array(['ACT'])                                                                
In [155]: x                                                                                    
Out[155]: array(['ACT'], dtype='<U3')
In [156]: x[0]                                                                                 
Out[156]: 'ACT'
In [157]: x[0][0]                                                                              
Out[157]: 'A'
In [158]: x[0][1]                                                                              
Out[158]: 'C'
```

===

I think collecting values in a list or dictionary would be simpler:

```
In [165]: txt = """>Sequence 1 
     ...: TCAGAACCAGTTATAAATTTATCATTTCCTTCTCCACTCCT 
     ...: >Sequence 2 
     ...: CCCACGCAGCCGCCCTCCTCCCCGGTCACTGACTGGTCCTG 
     ...: >Sequence 3 
     ...: TCGACCCTCTGGAACCTATCAGGGACCACAGTCAGCCAGGCAAG 
     ...: >Sequence 4 
     ...: AAAACACTTGAGGGAGCAGATAACTGGGCCAACCATGACTC"""                                         
In [166]: alist = []                                                                           
In [167]: for row in txt.splitlines(): 
     ...:     if row.startswith('>'): 
     ...:         x = [row] 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         x.append(row) 
     ...:         alist.append(x) 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [168]: alist                                                                                
Out[168]: 
[['>Sequence 1', 'TCAGAACCAGTTATAAATTTATCATTTCCTTCTCCACTCCT'],
 ['>Sequence 2', 'CCCACGCAGCCGCCCTCCTCCCCGGTCACTGACTGGTCCTG'],
 ['>Sequence 3', 'TCGACCCTCTGGAACCTATCAGGGACCACAGTCAGCCAGGCAAG'],
 ['>Sequence 4', 'AAAACACTTGAGGGAGCAGATAACTGGGCCAACCATGACTC']]
In [169]: dd = {key:val for key,val in alist}                                                  
In [170]: dd                                                                                   
Out[170]: 
{'>Sequence 1': 'TCAGAACCAGTTATAAATTTATCATTTCCTTCTCCACTCCT',
 '>Sequence 2': 'CCCACGCAGCCGCCCTCCTCCCCGGTCACTGACTGGTCCTG',
 '>Sequence 3': 'TCGACCCTCTGGAACCTATCAGGGACCACAGTCAGCCAGGCAAG',
 '>Sequence 4': 'AAAACACTTGAGGGAGCAGATAACTGGGCCAACCATGACTC'}
```

So basic processing of those strings:

```
In [171]: [len(val) for key,val in alist]                                                      
Out[171]: [41, 41, 44, 41]
In [172]: [val.count('T') for key,val in alist]                                                
Out[172]: [16, 7, 6, 6]
In [173]: [val.count('C') for key,val in alist]                                                
Out[173]: [12, 21, 15, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

it returns 84 while the type is S99 because the maximum length found was 99, so the type would be the S99, how you read from the file is not that right, and a better way to manage ur data is using `dict`, I dont know if it will suit your next needs but here is it:

```
seq={}
with open("file") as f:
    for line in f:
        seq[line]=next(f)
```

here it will read two lines at a time, so the first `line` has the sequence 1, next(f) has the seq TGC....., if happened that the file is not consistently ordered use if statement

Answer (score 1):

I just found this thesis, maybe it would help you to keep looking.
https://pastel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01762479/document

TL;DR
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

python https://louisabraham.github.io/notebooks/suffix_arrays.html